# Can't get file information from file uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a file uploader (HTML/CSS/Jquery), lets call it `uploader_1`, and another with just (HTML, PHP), `uploader_2`. I'm trying to make all files to be uploaded in the end of my form by `uploader_1`. For some reason, after adapting the code and everything, in my validation php file, i'm able to get `$_FILES` with all the information from `uploader_2`, however, nothing from `uploader_1` appears, not on the `$_FILES` nor in `$_POST`.

**Uploader_1**

HTML

```
<section class="col col-sm-5 rui" id="mupload5">
   <label class="label" for="file5">
       <b>Example</b>
       <p>Description</p>
   </label>
   <div class="file-uploader__message-area">
      <p>Select a file</p>
   </div>
   <div class="file-chooser">
      <input type="file" class="file-chooser__input" id="file5">
   </div>
   <?php
   listPdf($id, 5);
   ?>
</section>
```

Jquery

```
 //jQuery plugin
(function( $ ) {

   $.fn.uploader = function( options ) {
     var settings = $.extend({
       MessageAreaText: "There is no file selected.",
       MessageAreaTextWithFiles: "File list:",
       DefaultErrorMessage: "Failed opening file.",
       BadTypeErrorMessage: "Invalid type of file.",
       acceptedFileTypes: ['pdf', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'tif', 'tiff', 'png', 'xps', 'doc', 'docx',
        'fax', 'wmp', 'ico', 'txt', 'cs', 'rtf', 'xls', 'xlsx']
     }, options );

     var uploadId = 1;
     //update the messaging 
      $('.file-uploader__message-area p').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);

     //create and add the file list and the hidden input list
     var fileList = $('<ul class="file-list"></ul>');
     var hiddenInputs = $('<div class="hidden-inputs hidden"></div>');
     $('.file-uploader__message-area').after(fileList);
     $('.file-list').after(hiddenInputs);

    //when choosing a file, add the name to the list and copy the file input into the hidden inputs
     $('.file-chooser__input').on('change', function(){
        var file = $('.file-chooser__input').val();
        var fileName = (file.match(/([^\\\/]+)$/)[0]);

       //clear any error condition
       $('.file-chooser').removeClass('error');
       $('.error-message').remove();

       //validate the file
       var check = checkFile(fileName);
       if(check === "valid") {

         // move the 'real' one to hidden list 
         $('.hidden-inputs').append($('.file-chooser__input')); 

         //insert a clone after the hiddens (copy the event handlers too)
         $('.file-chooser').append($('.file-chooser__input').clone({ withDataAndEvents: true})); 

         //add the name and a remove button to the file-list
         $('.file-list').append('<li style="display: none;"><span class="file-list__name">' + fileName + '</span><button class="removal-button" data-uploadid="'+ uploadId +'"></button></li>');
         $('.file-list').find("li:last").show(800);

         //removal button handler
         $('.removal-button').on('click', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

           //remove the corresponding hidden input
           $('.hidden-inputs input[data-uploadid="'+ $(this).data('uploadid') +'"]').remove(); 

           //remove the name from file-list that corresponds to the button clicked
           $(this).parent().hide("puff").delay(10).queue(function(){$(this).remove();});

           //if the list is now empty, change the text back 
           if($('.file-list li').length === 0) {
             $('.file-uploader__message-area').text(options.MessageAreaText || settings.MessageAreaText);
           }
         });

         //so the event handler works on the new "real" one
         $('.hidden-inputs .file-chooser__input').removeClass('file-chooser__input').attr('data-uploadId', uploadId); 

         //update the message area
         $('.file-uploader__message-area').text(options.MessageAreaTextWithFiles || settings.MessageAreaTextWithFiles);

         uploadId++;

       } else {
         //indicate that the file is not ok
         $('.file-chooser').addClass("error");
         var errorText = options.DefaultErrorMessage || settings.DefaultErrorMessage;

         if(check === "badFileName") {
           errorText = options.BadTypeErrorMessage || settings.BadTypeErrorMessage;
         }

         $('.file-chooser__input').after('<p class="error-message">'+ errorText +'</p>');
       }
     });

     var checkFile = function(fileName) {
       var accepted          = "invalid",
           acceptedFileTypes = this.acceptedFileTypes || settings.acceptedFileTypes,
           regex;

       for ( var i = 0; i < acceptedFileTypes.length; i++ ) {
         regex = new RegExp("\\." + acceptedFileTypes[i] + "$", "i");

         if ( regex.test(fileName) ) {
           accepted = "valid";
           break;
         } else {
           accepted = "badFileName";
         }
       }

       return accepted;
    };
  }; 
}( jQuery ));

//init 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fileUploader').uploader({
    MessageAreaText: "Select a file."
  });
});
```

**Uploader_2**

HTML

```
<section class="col col-sm-5 rui">
    <label class="label" for="file6"><b>IPO e/ou Documentos Técnicos</b></label>
       <div class="upload-control">
          <input type="file"  class="input-sm  " name="file6" id="file6" style="height: 34px;" <?= $d; ?>  />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger force-auto-width add" aria-label="Left Align" id="deleteipo" >
             <span class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
          <?php  
             listPdf($id, 6);
          ?>
</section>
```

Now where i want to get the file information is in the PHP which is my submit url..

PHP

```
print_r($_FILES);
                echo 'HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERE'.$_FILES['file5'];
                die();

                if ( $_FILES['file2']['size'] == 0 )
                {
                        $errors[12] = "Insert file 2";
                }else{
            unset($errors[12]);
                }

                if ($_POST['waranty'] == 7 and $_FILES['file3']['size'] == 0)
                {
                        $errors[13] = "Insert file 3";
                }else{
            unset($errors[13]);
                }

                if ( $_FILES['file1']['size']['0'] == 0)
                {
                        $errors[14] = "Insert file 1";
                }else{
            unset($errors[14]);
                }
```

In the `print_r` or in the `echo` whatever i put in the Uploader_1, it doesnt show up... What's happening? What can i do? Been trying to get it in so many ways...

[Uploader_1 Template Codepen](http://codepen.io/heavenkinder/details/MeyOwj/)

PRINT_R RETURNS:

```
    Array ( 
    [file2] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) 
    [file3] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) 
[file1] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => )[tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
[file4] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )
[file6] => Array ( [name] => 17.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpHJGS6F [error] => 0 [size] => 7014 ) ) HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERE
```

Comment: Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

So i got updates. I managed to the get files into the `$_FILES`. So i can now use the new upload (Upload 1) to do what i needed to do. But i have a new problem now. I have 6 sections that need to upload files, different files. I can have 1 100% working, but having a second one will ruin everything. You can see the demonstration on this code pen.

**1 upload section** : http://codepen.io/heavenkinder/pen/BzzPrX

**2 upload sections** : http://codepen.io/heavenkinder/pen/XKKBBa

After insering 1 file, no matter where, everything stops working, or works porly. I have no idea why and i've been trying to seperate both file inputs but have the same, let's say template. Should i separate the javascript? Give different names to the inputs in the HTML and have javascript for each?